# Disable "Module does not export identifier" warning in GHC

Tags: haskell, compiler-warnings, ghc

Compiling the following code:

```
import Prelude hiding (nonExistent)
main = return ()
```

With `ghc -Wall` gives:

```
test.hs:1:1: Warning:
    Module `Prelude' does not export `nonExistent'
```

Is there a `-fno-XXX` flag that disables this specific warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the flag myself: `-fno-warn-dodgy-imports`:

Besides what is stated in the documentation:

> -fwarn-dodgy-imports:
>   Causes a warning to be emitted when a datatype T is imported with all constructors, i.e. T(..), but has been exported abstractly, i.e. T.

it also seems to enable/disable the specific warning I gave in my question.

Comment: There was [a change in behavior of this flag](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7167) but they forgot to update the documentation simultaneously, so some versions of GHC have the new behavior but not the documentation for it.  Before this change, the case you want to use was actually an *error* and could not be disabled.